# How to keep drop down menu sub navigation transition consistent when entering and leaving main links?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've created a drop down menu where each main link has a `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` event attached that first of all checks if there is a sub nav list associated with the link and then slides the menu into visibility. This works fine if you enter link 1 and leave the dropdown slides in then slides out but if you enter link 1 and then hover over link 2 the `slideUp()` consistency has gone, ideally i would like to make sure the active menu has closed before the new `mouseenter` code is run again. Can anyone suggest how I can achieve this?

**Link to fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/f3ZpN/1/

**JS**

```
var mainNav = $('.main-nav'),
    topLevelLinks = mainNav.children('li'),
    subNav = $('.sub-nav-panel'),
    subNavPanel,
    isActive = false,
    inner,
    innerLink;

topLevelLinks.on({
    mouseenter: function () {
        var el = $(this);

        if (el.children('.sub-nav').length > 0) {
            inner = el.children('.sub-nav');

            subNav.stop(true, true).slideDown(function () {
                inner.fadeIn();
            });
        }
    },
    mouseleave: function () {
        //make sure this finishes before mouseenter is run again?
        inner.fadeOut(function() {
            subNav.slideUp();
        });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You only want to call `subNav.slideUp()` if there are no submenus still visible. Here is a simple fix using your existing code: http://jsfiddle.net/PkAw3/ It still isn't perfect, but might help you along.

```
if (topLevelLinks.children('.sub-nav').filter(":visible").length === 0) {
    subNav.slideUp();
}
```

### Update based on comments

A little brain teaser... So we don't want to call mouseenter's animation until mouseleave's animation is done and vice versa. You can do this using the `promise()` and `done()` [jQuery functions](http://api.jquery.com/promise/). By default, `promise()` will wait until all the element's animations are complete before executing `done()`. Check out the update on jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/F75yV/1/

Comment: hey thanks, is it possible though instead if just transitioning the links when I change to new link for the subnav to animate up and then the new one slidedown like what happens on the initial link hover?

Comment: Hey, your new fiddle doesn't seem to have the .promise() or .done() functions?

Comment: Oops, forgot to save it. Try it now.

Comment: Also, check out the hoverintent plugin. This will make it much easier for people to use the menu since it isn't as sensitive as mouse events.